# Run Spark with build-in Hive and Configuring a remote PostgreSQL database for the Hive Metastore

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am running Spark v1.0.1 with build-in Hive (Spark install with SPARK_HIVE=true sbt/sbt assembly/assembly)

I also config Hive to store Metastore in PostgreSQL database as instruction:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html

I could config Hive (not build-in with Spark) to use PostgreSQL but I don't know how to get it work with Hive in Spark

In the instruction, I see that I need to put or link postgresql-jdbc.jar to hive/lib so that Hive could include the postgresql-jdbc when it run

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql-jdbc
$ ln -s /usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc.jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/postgresql-jdbc.jar
```

With Build-in Hive in Spark, where should I put the postgresql-jdbc.jar to get it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the solution for my problem. I need to add `CLASSPATH` for `SPARK` so that build-in Hive could use `postgresql-jdbc4.jar`

I add 3 environment variables:

```
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc4.jar"
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH
export SPARK_SUBMIT_CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH
```

**SPARK_CLASSPATH** is used for **spark-shell**

**SPARK_SUBMIT_CLASSPATH** is used for **spark-submit** (I am not sure)

Now I could use `spark-shell` with build-in Hive which config to use `Metastore in Postgres`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. You can continue to use your own hive installation. You need to put a copy of `hive-site.xml` (or make a symlink) under `$SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml`
2. If you want to use the built-in hive: you need to modify the `$SPARK_HOME/hive-<version>/conf/hive-site.xml` .
     Inside the `hive-site.xml` you need to modify the `javax.jdo.option.*` values. Along the lines of the following:

   ```
   <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
    <value>true</value>
      </property>
      <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hivedb</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
      <value>******</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
      <value>******</value>
    </property>
   ```

Comment: I put `hive-site.xml` to `$SPARK_HOME/conf` but It does not work. I think when I put `hive-site.xml` this will become config for build-in Hive.

My `hive-site.xml` included all config as you recommended in option 2

Comment: I could use shark with Hive, but I need use Hive on Spark because I want to use pyspark to write code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I originally put spark not shark. I misread, now will go back to spark.

Comment: I also do not find hive directory in SPARK_HOME. if I can put postgresql-jdbc.jar in hive/lib in SPARK installation, I could solve my issue. Do you have any suggetion?

Comment: The hive directory is for if you use shark. You are not using that however. I have updated my answer

Comment: It seems as though this suggestion may work in Spark 1.3 but not Spark 1.2. Has anyone experienced this?