# Problems with Apache Spark to consult a table

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark, hiveql

I try spark and hive, 
I want select one table

```
hiveContext.hql("select * from final_table").collect()
```

but I have this error

```
ERROR Hive: NoSuchObjectException(message:default.final_table table not found)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_table(HiveMetaStore.java:1569)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:106)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.get_table(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1008)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:90)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getTable(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1000)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:974)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.lookupRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$2.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$OverrideCatalog$$super$lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:141)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
```

but when I try this

```
hiveContext.hql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (key INT, value STRING)")
```

I haven't any problem and the table is created.

Any ideas about this problem, any solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which command do you use to start Spark? Most likely you haven't set up the usage of Hive metastore the right way, which means each time you start your cluster you are creating new temporary local metastore. To use the Hive metastore, follow these guides: ([Run Spark with build-in Hive and Configuring a remote PostgreSQL database for the Hive Metastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151307/run-spark-with-build-in-hive-and-configuring-a-remote-postgresql-database-for-th) and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables). This way the tables created by you will persist between cluster restarts, in Hive metastore.